# react hook useContext giving null value in my props.children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-context

I am new in reactjs hooks. I have a component which opens a socket from the server. Now I want to pass the props from my parent component which is the `QueueWebSocket` to my other component which is wrapped by my parent component.

Here is my parent component:

```
import { useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { getDjangoWebsocketHost } from 'components/global/function/env';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

// initialize websocket context
const QueueContext = createContext(null);

// export websocket context
export { QueueContext }

// initialize handler for websocket connection
// before DOM is ready
let wsInit = null;


const QueueWebsocket = (props) => {
    const { children } = props;
    // websocket payload
    const [responsePayload, setResponsePayload] = useState(null);
    // handler for websocket connection when DOM is ready
    const [ws, setWs] = useState(null);
    // state for checking if websocket connection has been established
    const [wsReady, setWsReady] = useState(false);
    // state for holding data received from the websocket connection
    // this is sent across all logged in PGAN users when data is available
    // const [globalNotification, setGlobalNotification] = useState(payload);    

    // function for sending CONNECT event
    const connectEvent = ({ requestPayload }) => {
      if (wsReady) {
        encodedRequestPayload = new Uint8Array(JSON.stringify(
          requestPayload).split('').map(
            c => c.charCodeAt(0)
          )
        ).buffer;
        ws.send(encodedRequestPayload);
      }
    };

  // function for sending message via websocket connection
  // const sendMessage = ({ requestPayload }) => {
  //   console.log(requestPayload)
  //   let encodedRequestPayload = new Uint8Array(JSON.stringify(
  //     requestPayload).split('').map(
  //       c => c.charCodeAt(0)
  //     )
  //   ).buffer;
  //   console.log(encodedRequestPayload)
  //   ws.send(encodedRequestPayload);
  // };
  
  // function for opening connection,
  // monitoring closed connection,
  // and monitoring incoming data from the websocket connection
  const ws_connect = (s) => {
    if (s) {

      // set 'ws' and 'wsReady' states
      // when websocket connection is opened
      s.onopen = () => {
        setWs(s);
        setWsReady(true)
      }
  
      // if connection is closed,
      // attempt to reconnect after 1 second
      s.onclose = (e) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          ws_connect();
        }, 1000);
      }
  
      s.onmessage = (e) => {
        // the data received from the websocket connection
        let receivedData = e.data;

        // the payload is in JSON,
        // but our websocket server sends it as binary data
        // so we need to parse it to be able for JS to understand
        let binary_data = new Uint8Array(receivedData).reduce((p, c) => p + String.fromCharCode(c), '');
        receivedData = JSON.parse(binary_data);

        // assign the 'payload' object to 'data'
        // this time, we now have the parsed value of the websocket message
        receivedData = receivedData['payload'];

        // deconstruct the payload
        // expectedly, we expect the ff. as default:
        
        // message    -> any message from the websocket connection
        // event      -> name of the corresponding event from the websocket connection
        // data       -> any additional information
        const { event, data } = receivedData;
        
        // check what event was invoked
        // and perform respective operation
        switch(event) {
          case "EVENT_CALL":
            if(data) {
              // console.log(data);
              setResponsePayload((prev) => ({...prev, event , data}));
            }              
            break;          
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
     
    }
  }
  
  // function for running ws_connect() function above,
  // ONLY when the DOM is ready
  const initializeConnection = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {      
      wsInit = new WebSocket(
        `${getDjangoWebsocketHost()}/ws/queuePage/test/`);        
      if (wsInit) {
        wsInit.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
        ws_connect(wsInit);
      }
    }
  };


  // attempt to connect to 'ws/login/'
  // when this component loads
  useEffect(() => {    
      initializeConnection();    
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <QueueContext.Provider 
      value={{
        responsePayload,        
      }}
    >
        { children }  
    </QueueContext.Provider>
  );

}

export default QueueWebsocket;
```

now i tried to wrapped my other component from the component above to get the `responsePayload` prop from my children component but it gives me null.

Here is what i tried:

```
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useContext } from 'react';

import { Row, Col, Divider } from 'antd';


import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import QueueWebsocket from 'components/global/function/websocket/queue_service/QueueWebsocket';

import {QueueContext} from 'components/global/function/websocket/queue_service/QueueWebsocket';



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    margin: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    paper: {    
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
  }));

const Test = (props) => {    
    
    const queueContext = useContext(QueueContext);    

   

    const classes = useStyles();

    const router = useRouter();

    const handle = useFullScreenHandle();

    console.log(queueContext);

    return (
        <QueueWebsocket>            
            <Row>                
                {console.log(queueContext)} 
            </Row> 
        </QueueWebsocket>
    )

}

export default Test;
```

Comment: What gets printed out if you add this to the parent `useEffect(() => {console.log(responsePayload)})` ? I'm wondering if you can isolate this to the parent or child. Also, in the child, you can't render the output of `console.log` as it's undefined. If you want to see the value try `JSON.stringify(queueContext)` in your jsx instead.

Comment: @Willow nothing displays. any help or solution how can i pass this using context? it passes an error of undefined

Comment: `Test` isn't getting wrapped by `QueueContext.Provider` so it doesn't have access to the `QueueContext` context. You need to call `useContext(QueueContext)` inside a child component of the context provider. Context gets passed down from the provider to the children who can then consume it.